# Efficient way to fix code using git

Tags: git

When I want to do a small fix in my code using git, I would do the following:

```
git checkout -b fix
# fix the code
git commit -a
git checkout master
git rebase fix
git branch -d fix
```

because this way it happens all the time for me, I wonder if there is a more efficient way? Just any method to put these commands together or something similar.

Most notably I would like to put the last three steps together in a command like `git complete-fix`. How could I manage to set up a command like that? Aliases would not be sufficient for this case, because the branch name won't  be always "fix" but could be different. I also do not want to pass the current branch name with a alias parameter.

Comment: You could create an alias, or use a premade set of scripts such as Git Flow.

Comment: Rebasing `master` in any form would seem to be an unconventional/unlikely way of doing things, because you're rewriting the history of the most highly trafficked and shared branch in your repository.  More likely, fixes would be made by just laying down new commits on top of `master`, I think.

Comment: you can replace git rebase with git merge, its just an example for a git-svn Iam using. And yes, I would like to stay with branching because of its benefits.

Comment: using aliases would mean, that the branch needs to use the same name always, mmhh

Comment: @Asara `git merge` is preferable to `git rebase` in this particular situation. See my answer.

Comment: Why are you rebasing master on top of your fix, instead of the other way around? That seems entirely the wrong thing to do. If you *are* going to use rebase, rebase fix on top of master (if necessary).

Comment: In any case, you can parameterize aliases, so an alias would be the way to go, or you could always create a bash script if you require more advanced logic.

Comment: I have some bash scripts that work out the current branch, you can see them in my repository, here's one of them: https://github.com/lassevk/GitToolbox/blob/master/git-ahead#L9

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash (or a similar shell), you can do this with an alias:

```
alias git-complete-fix='branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) ; if [ -n "${branch}" ]; then git checkout master ; git rebase ${branch} ; git branch -d ${branch} ; fi'
```

If you want it to behave like a new git command (as in your `git complete-fix` example, you could instead put the contents of that alias into a shell script named `git-complete-fix`, then make the script executable and put it somewhere on your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
if [ -n "${branch}" ]; then
    git checkout master
    git rebase ${branch}
    git branch -d ${branch}
fi
```

You could then invoke the script using either `git-complete-fix` or `git complete-fix`.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest instead of

```
git checkout master
git rebase fix
git branch -d fix
```

do

```
git checkout master
git merge fix
git branch -d fix
```

This places the newest commits as the newest ones on `master` rather than the oldest ones as happens with `git rebase`.

For more details about suggested workflows with git, read [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices) on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: that was not the question here

Comment: @Asara I misunderstood then. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I dont know what iI should clarify, I asked about a more efficient way to handle the several commands. Your method is just replacing rebase with merge. And if someone uses merge or rebase might depend on several things not related to the question.

Comment: @Asara Okay, I understand now. Your question is about automating the sequence of commands. I got hung up on how you use `git rebase`. The sequence of commands in your original question are more appropriate for `git merge`. If you are doing `git rebase`, the sequence of commands is very different.